# Javascript is Loading Page Too Soon - Django Edit Form

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, javascript-objects, fetch-api

I'm trying to edit an existing post (form) on my site but when I click 'edit' I get this in the console: Fetch finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_post/18".
Status is 201 so I think the page is skipping over most of the javascript and directly posting it/saving to server. Also when I click 'edit' a text box is immediately supposed to appear with my post text already there. But this never opens, it just says fetch finished loading appropriately in the console.

How can I make sure all the Javascript is run first? I tried using preventDefault and keep running into Uncaught type errors. I'm pretty new to Javascript so I'm still learning this.

For example, one thing I tried within the event_handeler function was:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#textarea").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).innerHTML += "Sorry!";
event.preventDefault();
})
```

But I got uncaught type errors.

```
function edit_handeler(element) {
  id = element.getAttribute("data-id");

  document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).style.display = "none";

edit_btn = document.querySelector(`#edit-btn-${id}`);
edit_btn.textContent = "Save";
edit_btn.setAttribute("class", "text-success edit");
if (edit_btn.textContent == "Save") {
edit_post(id, document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).value); //here

edit_btn.textContent = "Edit";
edit_btn.setAttribute("class", "text-primary edit");
}}


function edit_post(id, post) {
 const body = document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).value; 

fetch(`/edit_post/${id}`, {

method: "POST",
body: JSON.stringify({
body:body
})


 }).then((res) => {
 document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).textContent = post;
 document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).style.display = "block";
 document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).style.display = "none";
 document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).value = post.trim(); 
  });
 }
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def edit_post(request, pk): #used to take in pk here also

    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)  # was id=pk

    form = PostForm(instance=post)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
          
            return JsonResponse({}, status=201) # this works to edit and save to db
    else:
        if request.method == "GET":           
            form = PostForm(instance=post)
            form_for_post = {'form': PostForm()}

            return render(request, "network/make_post.html", {
                "post": post,
                "form_for_post": form,
    })
```

relevant urls.py

```
path('edit_post/<str:pk>', views.edit_post, name="edit_post"),
```

relevant html - the first part is the textarea that should open up when you click 'edit.'
Next part is the edit button.

```
span id="post-content-{{i.id}}" class="post">{{i.text}}</span> <br> 
                <textarea data-id="{{i.id}}" id="post-edit-{{i.id}}" 
style="display:none;" class="form-control textarea" row="3">{{i.text}}</textarea>

<button class="btn-btn primary" data-id="{{i.id}}" id="edit-btn-{{i.id}}" 
onclick="edit_handeler(this)" >Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

first the code format is a mess and really difficult to read, try to format it better using Prettier or anythin else before uploading next time.

To my knowledge `onsubmit` listener can be only bind to `<form>` element and it makes sense, you do not submit textarea but the form in which it's included.
Therefore you should target `<form>` elements with the `addEventListener`.

Also when a listener is called, the browser inserts en `event object` as a first argument into it.

> Event listeners only take one argument, the Event Object, which is automatically passed to the listener, and the return value is ignored.
> [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#getting_data_into_and_out_of_an_event_listener)

and if you want to access attributes of the element you can do that by accessing `event.target`

One possible way of doing what you need:
JS:

```
function onsubmitHandler(event, url, ...others) {
  // prevents form from submitting and reloading the page
  event.preventDefault();
  // accessing element which caused firing this eventListener
  // in our case that is the form element
  let form = event.target;
  // now we need the textarea and its value
  let textarea = form.querySelector("textarea");
  let content = textarea.value;

  // other steps
  fetch(url, ...).then(res => ..)
}
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit='onsubmitHandler(event, url, ...others)'> 
  <textarea>..</textarea>
  <button type="submit">..</button>
</form>
```

This way, the button triggers onsubmit event which is captured by the form element in which the button resides in.

and of course, you can pass values from Django template as:

```
<form onsubmit='onsubmitHandler(event, {{ url }})'>
```

Key points:

- onsubmit or addEventListener("submit") fires on the form itself therefore it is the event's target and reloads the page - that is its native behaviour - which you can stop programatically `event.preventDefault()` inside the listener callback's function (the onsubmitHandler in our case)

> Note that the submit event fires on the  element itself, and not on any  or  inside it.

- If you use `<form action="https://example.com" method="POST">` and do not attach any event listener to it, it will collect named inputs inside the form ` and append them to action url as query parameters => "https://example.com?car=car" and sends POST request with that url to a server. And it does not wait for anything and reloads the page.

I am not an expert and doing the same course as you are so if there is a mistake or something is unclear I apologize and feel free to ask.